# A conjecture of Cheeger about intersection cohomology and $L^2$- cohomology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, cohomology, kahler-manifolds, intersection-cohomology

> Let $X$ be a projective variety and let $D$ be a simple normal
>   crossings divisor on $X$
>
> Does $$IH^*(X;\mathbb C)\cong H_{(2)}^*(X\setminus D;\mathbb C)$$ hold
>   true for each Kähler metric on $X\setminus D$?  Is there any
>   counterexample?
>
> What about the Fubini-Study metric on $X\setminus D$? (This is a
>   conjecture of Cheeger) What about the case when the Kähler metric on
>   $X\setminus D$ has a conic model?, a cusp model(Is OK), or a
>   combination of these two models?

Comment: What is a reference for Cheeger's conjecture ?

Comment: conjecture 9 http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1990.1/Main/icm1990.1.0735.0746.ocr.pdf . He said something about conical metric. But it is far than the definition of conical model of Tian-Yau

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but you don't seem to be getting any answers.

First of all, I would be surprised if holds for *any* Kähler metric (e.g. for one with really bad singularities along $D$) but I don't have a counterexample*. Regarding the case of Fubini-Study metric, for isolated singularities, I believe it was
settled positively by Ohsawa: "Cheeger-Goreski [Goresky]-MacPherson's conjecture for the varieties with isolated singularities."  Math. Z. 206 (1991).  I don't know the status in general. I believe that there was a gap in a later paper by author on this.

There has been a lot of work with other metrics. For example, you can look at work on Zucker's conjecture, which was proved by Looijenga and Saper-Stern. Also for Poincaré type metrics, allowing coefficients in a variation of Hodge structure, there is the work by Cattani-Kaplan-Schmid and Kashiwara-Kawai. This provides the analytic basis for Saito's theory of Hodge modules.

*(added later) Here's a counterexample. Choose a diffeomorphism $f$ between $\mathbb{C}$ and the disk $D$. Pulling back the Poincaré metric gives a Kähler metric such that $\dim H^1_{(2)}(\mathbb{P}-\{\infty\})=\infty$ because $f^*(z^ndz)$ gives an infinite family of harmonic $L^2$ forms. However intersection cohomology is finite dimensional.